# Expected xxx to be a date after consuming a service

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, date

I'm consuming a REST service with angular $http, then I store the json response in my scope.
On a page, I want to bind data to a form.

As Date properties received from REST service is in String format inside the JSON, my input date text doesn't bind the field in JSON.
I get an error in console "Expected '1981-04-01' to be a date".

Is there a way to make angular consider this field as date ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

JSON does not natively consider dates (I think neither XML does) and most backend technologies do not convert dates (in whatever format they handle them) to other format than strings. This is true for PHP, Java, and Python.

So you get null, strings, numbers, booleans, and nested structures (objects, arrays) from the back-end.

In the front-end you have Angular with $http. You're out of luck there too: you receive only strings and such types of data without conversion. Even `ngResource` lacks of that capability. What you must do is, in the success data handler:

```
$http(...).success(function(data, more, params, here){
    $scope.data = data; //assuming you're retrieving the whole object. this line is up to you and your logic.
    $scope.data.mydatefield = new Date($scope.data.mydatefield);
});
```

MySQL-dates with the usual format are accepted as argument and behave as expected. But, again, with the info you provided, you're out of luck and must do it manually (well... it's not that hard - it's as I showed u ... perhaps storing, temporarily, the data in a local variable in order to not make the $scope flicker).